# Change anchor tag and img tag to RenderLink and RenderImage respectively

Tags: glass-mapper

In my code I have an anchor tag which has an external link or a backend function is called as the href value.
How to convert that to RenderLink?

For example I have the following code in which I am calling a function `GetShareLink` from backend.

```
<a href="<%=GetShareLink(items)%>" target="_blank">
    <i class="icon <%=GetClass(items.Icon.ToString()) %>"></i>
</a>
```

Same goes to image tag also. How to use RenderImage here?

```
<img src="./static/img/content-text/optional_links.png">
```

Comment: I would advise you to participate the devolpment course of sitecore. They deal with these kind of problems

Comment: Are you asking how you can achieve the same result using RenderLink and RenderImage?

Comment: It is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Both RenderLink and RenderImage work exclusively with Sitecore items and their fields. What you're trying to achieve is not possible using these methods.